Executing two commands sequentially in a lambda function
I'm trying to create a key binding that will execute magit-status, wait for me to decide whether I want to save any files (magit-status does this), and then execute an npm command in the directory of the file where I invoked the key binding (which isn't necessarily the root of the repository).
From what I read online, I thought it'd work like this:
(defun execute-lintfix ()
  (interactive)
  (call-process-shell-command "npm run lintfix &" nil 0))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-g") (lambda () (interactive) (magit-status) (execute-lintfix)))

However, this only opens magit status but does not execute my npm command. If I remove (magit-status), it does execute my npm command, so the problem seems to be with my lambda function, not with execute-lintfix. How do I call both of these functions?

Why do you think your function isn't being called?

Other comments: If you have no need to call execute-lintfix interactively (via M-x or a key binding), then it needn't have (interactive).  The key sequence C-c C-g isn't reserved for end users, so consider instead using C-c followed by a letter (which is reserved for end users).  I strongly recommend not binding keys to lambda forms; use named functions (and include docstrings) -- lambdas are really rubbish for introspection purposes (e.g. when you ask Emacs which function that key sequence is bound to).

@phils It probably got executed but in a directory without a package.json, and then it terminated quickly. I used the heuristic of checking plasma-systemmonitor because eslint is absolutely javascript and takes an astonishingly long time to execute compared to other linters. Easily enough time to check a process monitor for a long-running process that's putting full load on all CPU cores.

I expect this is your problem:

(magit-status) switches to the magit status buffer, which has a default-directory of the repository root.
You are consequently running (execute-lintfix) in that buffer.

So this isn't happening:

... then execute an npm command in the directory of the file where I invoked the key binding (which isn't necessarily the root of the repository).

You'll want to capture the default-directory value prior to calling magit-status, and subsequently call your shell command with default-directory let-bound to the original value.

Thank you very much! I'll accept this answer and post the working code I now have as a separate answer for others to use. It's too long to include in this comment and I don't think it'd be nice to edit your answer and make it look like it's your code because I don't know what I'm doing and my code might be slightly wrong (even though it works for me as far as I can tell after a quick testing).

The code I'm now using thanks to @phils' answer:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-g")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((current-directory default-directory))
      (magit-status)
      (let ((default-directory current-directory))
        (execute-lintfix)))))


You didn't heed @phils's advice in his comment: "I strongly recommend not binding keys to lambda forms; use named functions (and include docstrings) -- lambdas are really rubbish for introspection purposes (e.g. when you ask Emacs which function that key sequence is bound to)."

That aside the code looks fine, although you might want to reconsider the names.  It's a good idea to name-space all of your custom function names with some unique prefix to ensure they can't ever clash with code from other libraries; and for the same reason, if you're using dynamic binding for your code, it's a good idea to restrict temporary let-bound variables to names without hyphens (as only a relatively small number of dynamic variables have names without hyphens, and third-party libraries can be expected not to do so, so you can avoid naming conflicts that way).
